# Shortcut for parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics, parameterized, generic-type-argument

I'm working with code where I need to generate a lot of `List<Map<String,Object>>` and it's unwieldy to have to type e.g. `bob = new List<Map<String,Object>>` all the time.

I tried to create an empty class a la

```
class ListMap extends List<Map<String,Object>> {}
```

but then methods that take `List<Map<String,Object>>` don't accept a `new ListMap()` as their type, and I get errors from methods that return `List<Map<String,Object>>` if I assign them to a `ListMap`. Basically I want Java to treat my ListMap as the same as a List> ... because it is, at least via inheritance, in theory.

Comment: `class ListMap extends List<Map<String,Object>>` can't be valid because a class can't `extends` an interface. Choose an implementation of `List` (such as `ArrayList`), and `extends` that: `class ListMap extends ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>{}`

Comment: A list is an interface you can't extends it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have methods returning `List<Map<String,Object>>`, but want to assign that to a variable of type `ListMap`, and the `List<Map<String,Object>>` might be implemented as an `ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>`, you cannot make it directly assignment-compatible with a `ListMap`.

So, you need to wrapper the returned object with a delegating proxy. First, create a generic delegating class for `List`. They are easy to create, e.g. Eclipse can create all the delegating methods for you by selecting "`Generate Delegate Methods...`" from the "`Source`" pull-down menu.

It should look like this:

```
public class DelegatingList<E> implements List<E> {
    private final List<E> list;
    protected DelegatingList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.list.isEmpty();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return this.list.contains(o);
    }
    // many other delegating methods from List
}
```

Now define your `ListMap` interface:

```
public interface ListMap extends List<Map<String,Object>> {
    public static ListMap newArrayList() {
        return wrap(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    public static ListMap wrap(List<Map<String,Object>> list) {
        if (list instanceof ListMap)
            return (ListMap) list;
        class Wrapper extends DelegatingList<Map<String,Object>> implements ListMap {
            protected Wrapper() {
                super(list);
            }
        }
        return new Wrapper();
    }
}
```

It is now simple to use:

```
ListMap myListMap = ListMap.newArrayList();
methodAcceptingListOfMapOfStringToObject(myListMap);
```

```
ListMap x = ListMap.wrap(methodReturningListOfMapOfStringToObject());
```

Comment: Hairier than I'd hoped -- I wanted to avoid having to reimplement every List method with a wrapper -- but it makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In such case the best course of action is to add conversion methods to your `ListMap` to and from `List<Map<String, Object>>`... know you could choose to implement `ListMap` in away that is affected by changes in the original `List` if you can keep a reference to that and implement `ListMap` by delegation or keep changes separated in which case you co make `ListMap` to extends any of the `List` implementations in `java.util.*`.

```
class ListMap extends AbstractList<Map<String, Object>> {

   public ListMap(final Map<String, Object> list) { super(list); } 
   // or
   public static ListMap fromList(final List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
       if (list instanceof ListMap) {
          return (ListMap) list;
       } else {
          return new ListMap(list);
       }
   } 
}
```

Using the static method above allow you to save the instantiation if it happens that the list provided is in fact a `ListMap`.