# Why can't my Java ArrayList be cast into an interface that extends List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface

Why can't my Java List be cast into an interface that extends list?
I have an interface that defines a list type:

```
public interface RefInItemsListInput <T extends Object> extends List<T> {}
```

which is used in 3 places and will have a builder that makes it.
I have another class which accepts RefInItemsListInput:

```
public static class RefInItems1 extends JsonSchema {
        public static RefInItemsList validate(RefInItemsListInput arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException {
            return JsonSchema.validateList(RefInItems1.class, arg, configuration);
        }
}
```

And I call it in a test:

```
    @Test
    public void testPropertyNamedRefValidPasses() {
        // property named $ref valid
        RefInItems.RefInItems1.validate(
            (RefInItems.RefInItemsListInput)
            Arrays.asList(
                MapMaker.makeMap(
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                        "$ref",
                        "a"
                    )
                )
            ),
            configuration
        );
    }
```

My MapMaker class is:

```
/**
 * A builder for maps that allows in null values
 * Schema tests need this
 * Future schema doc code samples will need it
 */
public class MapMaker {
    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> makeMap(Map.Entry<K, V>... entries) {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

When I run my test, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class org.openapijsonschematools.client.components.schemas.RefInItems$RefInItemsListInput (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.openapijsonschematools.client.components.schemas.RefInItems$RefInItemsListInput is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

    at org.openapijsonschematools.client.components.schemas.RefInItemsTest.testPropertyNamedRefValidPasses(RefInItemsTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Why can't my ArrayList instance be cast to my interface that extends list?
I am using Java 11

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code.  You say you have this list : `RefInItemsListInput <T extends Object>`  but the method in question returns: `public static RefInItemsList validate(` ?  Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns an implementation of a `List` (in this case `ArrayList`, but you shouldn't be relying on that), but you're trying to cast an instance of `RefInItems.RefInItemsListInput`, which is incompatible.  `ArrayList` and `RefInItems.RefInItemsListInput` may implement `List`, but they are still two different objects.  They could be used in places where `List` is expected, but you couldn't pass and `ArrayList` to a method which required an instance of `RefInItems.RefInItemsListInput` or vice versa

Comment: So then what are my options here?
- Implement AbstractList to make a concrete instance of my List?
- Extend ArrayList to define RefInItemsListInput instead?

Comment: I can only refer you to [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2970947), and suggest you **program to the `List` interface**. `public static List<T> validate(List<T> arg, SchemaConfiguration configuration) throws ValidationException {` -- I notice you forgot about `T`.

Comment: One can do it with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370888/shortcut-for-parameterized-type

Comment: FYI, `<T extends Object>` can be simplified to `<T>`.

Comment: Because `Arrays.asList(...)` is not a `RefInItemsListInput`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because casting from a subclass (List) to a extended class (RefInItemsListInput) is not allowed.
The interface is an extension of List. A solution is to:

1. Define the desired interface type as an extension of List
2. Create a class that implements the object
3. Create a new instance of the class from step 2 using the List inputs

In code this looks like this:

```
    public interface RefInItemsListInput extends List<Object> {
        class RefInItemsListInputImpl extends ArrayList<Object> implements RefInItemsListInput {
            public RefInItemsListInputImpl(List<Object> inst) {
                super(inst);
            }
        }
        static RefInItemsListInput of(List<Object> inst) {
            return new RefInItemsListInputImpl(inst);
        }
    }
```

And the test code is:

```
    @Test
    public void testPropertyNamedRefValidPasses() {
        // property named $ref valid
        RefInItems.RefInItems1.validate(
            RefInItems.RefInItemsListInput.of(
            Arrays.asList(
                MapMaker.makeMap(
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                        "$ref",
                        "a"
                    )
                )
            )),
            configuration
        );
    }
```

Once can read all about it here and see some other solutions:

- [Shortcut for parameterized type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370888/shortcut-for-parameterized-type)

Remember that this`interface extends List<object>` solution will create an extra list, so it will use more memory than bare list types. If less space is needed, consider making the List type into a generic, and having a separate method that generates an instance of that generic.